# Build JSON based on JQuery clone elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, forms

I'm using `PHP 7` (Phalcon 3), `Bootstrap 3` and `JQuery 3`. Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Johngtrs/pen/WNNGeKa). When you click on the add button it will clone the form inline.

**`HTML`**

```
<div class="row form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <label>First name</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="form-control">          
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <label>Last name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="form-control">          
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <label>check</label> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="check">
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-add">Add</button>
```

**`JS`**

```
  $("#btn-add").click(function() {
    $('.row.form-inline:last').clone(true).insertAfter('.row.form-inline:last');

    // Don't care about this, it's a checkbox library 
    $('input').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
      increaseArea: '20%',
      checked: false
    });
    $('.row.form-inline:last .checkbox').iCheck('uncheck');
    return false;
  });
```

So now I need to send the data to the server but I don't know how can I create a good formatted `JSON` through `Ajax`.

I'd like to create an `JSON Array` based on the number of created clone like **this** :

```
[
  {
    "firstname" : "John",
    "lastname" : "Doe",
    "check" : true
  },
  {
    "firstname" : "Mark",
    "lastname" : "Davidson",
    "check" : false
  },
  {
    "firstname" : "Mike",
    "lastname" : "Green",
    "check" : true
  }
]
```

And in my `PHP` script I gonna loop through this data easily. So how can I build this `JSON array` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is the duplication of `id` attributes, which is invalid. You can change them to classes, or remove them.

Then, based on your HTML structure, you can use `map()` to build the array:

```
var data = $('.form-inline').map(function() {
  var $container = $(this);
  return {
    firstname: $container.find('.firstname').val(),
    lastname: $container.find('.lastname').val(),
    checkbox: $container.find('.checkbox').prop('checked'),
  }
}).get();
```

Here's a full working example:

```js
$("#btn-add").on('click', function() {
  $('.row.form-inline:last').clone(true).insertAfter('.row.form-inline:last');
});

$('#test').on('click', function() {
  var data = $('.form-inline').map(function() {
    var $container = $(this);
    return {
      firstname: $container.find('.firstname').val(),
      lastname: $container.find('.lastname').val(),
      checkbox: $container.find('.checkbox').prop('checked'),
    }
  }).get();
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row form-inline">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control firstname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control lastname">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
    <label>check</label> <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="check">
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-add">Add</button>

<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Comment: Awesome ! It's exactly what I need. Thank you so much

Comment: I just have a question about your container variable. What does mean the `$` on `$container` ?

Comment: Nothing, it's just a naming convention to show the variable holds a jQuery object. It has no other special meaning.